# Multi dimensional array for a form

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, validation

I want to check my input form with PHP.

And I want to fill an array with the false inputsbox name and the reason.

But I don't know how I get it multidimensional.

e.g.

```
$false = array();

if (!isset($_POST['name']) OR $_POST['name'] == "") {
    array_push($false, "name");
    //and here I want to to get a multi-dimension array and put the reason of the fales the the arraykey name
    //e.g. Sorry the name is missing!
}

if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) {
    array_push($false, "name");
    //and here I want to to get a multi-dimension array and put the reason of the fales the the arraykey name
    //e.g. Sorry the name is to short!
}
```

And now I want to get (if in the input form name stand nothing after submit) e.g.

```
false
(
    [0] => name
                (
                    [0] => Sorry the name is missing!
                    [1] => Sorry the name is to short!
                    [2] => etc etc
                )
    [1] => etc
                (
                    [0] => etc etc
                )
)
```

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: $false = array();

$false[] = $_POST;

something like that?

Comment: No. In my example I write in the array "false" the input "name" and now i want to put the reason to the to the array kay "name".

Comment: $false = array(); $false['name'][] = $_POST['name']; will work

Comment: Sorry just realised that someone below me had posted xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$false = array();

if (!isset($_POST['name']) OR $_POST['name'] == "") {
    $false['name'][] = 'Sorry the name is missing!';
}

if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) {
    $false['name'][] = 'Sorry the name is to short!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works... but now I cant find with in_array the key name. i want to test: if(in_array("name", $false)) { // do something }

Comment: if($false['name']) { //do something }

Comment: if( array_key_exists( 'name', $false ) ){ //do something }